# SQL Query help using UNION or nested queries

Tags: mysql, sql, union

I am trying to execute a query but its not working out so well for me. I got these tables:

```
create table spelare(
   Spnr char(13),
   Snamn varchar (20),
   primary key (Spnr)
)engine=innodb;


create table speltillfalle(
   starttid varchar (15),
   Tnamn varchar (20),
   Spnr char (13),
   resultat char (10),
   primary key (starttid, Tnamn, Spnr),
   foreign key (Tnamn) references tavling(Tnamn),
   foreign key (Spnr) references spelare(Spnr)
)engine=innodb;
```

What i want to do is the match 'Spnr' column from the table "spelare" with the Spnr column from the table "speltillfalle". I did that using this query:

```
SELECT Spnr FROM spelare UNION SELECT Spnr FROM speltillfalle;
```

This gave me all the Spnr values that matched in both tables. What i would like to do is the same thing AND add another condition. IT should return the same thing but only if the value of "resultat" column in the table "speltillfalle" is 'Diskad' for the corresponding matched Spnr.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Based on your description you simply add this as a WHERE-condition:

```
SELECT Spnr FROM spelare 
UNION 
SELECT Spnr FROM speltillfalle
WHERE resultat = 'Diskad';
```

Or you use a EXISTS:

```
SELECT Spnr FROM spelare AS s
WHERE EXISTS
 ( 
   SELECT * FROM speltillfalle AS sf
   WHERE s.Spnr = sf.Spnr
     AND resultat = 'Diskad'
 );
```

Or an IN:

```
SELECT Spnr FROM spelare AS s
WHERE Spnr IN
 ( 
   SELECT Spnr FROM speltillfalle AS sf
   WHERE resultat = 'Diskad'
 );
```

Both `IN` and `EXSISTS` are a more common solution than `UNION`:-)

Comment: Thank you. I used the exist method. I forgot to mention that the results should be displayed by the Snamn in spelare table. If you could just help with that would be grateful

Comment: @hamzah: What do mean by `be displayed by the Snamn`, ordered? Of course with `EXISTS` or `IN?` you can show/use all columns in the SELECT.

Comment: With the answer you gave me when all the conditions are met it gives me the Spnr of the match. What i would like for it to do is instead ONLY give me the Snamn of the match

Comment: @hamzah: Then simply change to `SELECT Snamn FROM...`

Comment: Omg. Im thinking way to complicated when it is so easy.. Thank you. Starting to understand this better

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Exists`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/exists-and-not-exists-subqueries.html) like this:

```
SELECT Spnr, Snamn 
FROM spelare 
WHERE EXISTS 
(
SELECT 1
FROM speltillfalle
WHERE resultat = 'Diskad'
AND Spnr = spelare.Spnr
);
```

Comment: Where is matching here? Table `speltillfalle` can contain row with unmatched `Spnr`.

Comment: oops, you are correct. I've jumped to the wrong conclusion. should be better using exists. I've edited my answer.

Comment: Thank you. What would i need to add if i wanted the result to display the Snamn of spelare table?

Answer (score 0):

I think you want `join`:

```
select sp.Spnr from spelare sp
join speltillfalle sf on sp.Spnr = sf.Spnr and sf.resultat = 'Diskad'
group by sp.Spnr
```

Comment: exists would be better here since this will result in all the columns from both tables, as well as possibly duplicatied rows...

Answer (score 0):

if i understand your question correctly then the answer may be

"select a.spnr,b.spnr from spelare a,speltillfalle b where a.spnr=b.spnr and b.resultat='Diskad'"

Comment: Hi, while you answer is basically correct the join is superfluous due to the foreign key constrain.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT s.Spnr 
  FROM spelare as s 
 INNER 
  JOIN speltillfalle as sf 
    on s.Spnr=sf.Spnr 
 where sf.Spnr = 'Diskad';
```

As you have applied a join on both these table and it returns all matching records for column Spnr we will just need to add one more condition as shown above for fecting only those records whoes value is 'Diskad'.

Comment: As mentioned before, the join is superfluous due to the foreign key constraint on the speltillfalle table.

Answer (score 0):

While you are asking "the Spnr values that matched in both tables" and "the match 'Spnr' column from the table *spelare* with the Spnr column from the table *speltillfalle*" you do not need an UNION.
In my book "matched" means they are present in both tables.

Spnr column on *speltillfalle* is defined as

```
foreign key (Spnr) references spelare(Spnr)
```

So, if *speltillfalle.Spnr* is not null (it could be because you didn't add any NOT NULL constraint) certainly does exist in the *spelare* table.
In this case

```
SELECT DISTINCT Spnr FROM speltillfalle WHERE resultat = 'Diskad' AND Spnr IS NOT NULL
```

does the job: the Spnr values you get from *speltillfalle* certainly do exist in *spelare* table, due to the foreign key constraint.